# simple html dom grabbing all <p> attribute

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I just learning about simple_html_dom.php, I try to get only all the p attribute content in entry-content class and make it to one paragraph or one sentence.

here the raw html file from the website that i want to get the content.

```
<div class="entry-content">
<p><img class="alignnone" src="xxxxxxxxxxx" width="800" height="450" /></p>
<p>data1<span id="more-287848"></span></p>
<p>data2</p>
<p>data3</p>
<p>data4</p>
<p>......</p>
<p>......</p>
<p>dataN</p>

<div class="wpa wpmrec">
            <a class="wpa-about" href="https://wordpress.com/about-these-ads/" rel="nofollow"></a>
            <div class="u">
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                (function(g){g.__ATA.initAd({sectionId:34789711, width:300, height:250});})(window);
                </script>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here my code to get it :

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/simple_html_dom.php';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file('https://xxxxxxxxx');
 $isi = $html->find('div[class="entry-content"]',0)->innertext;
?>
<table border="1">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $isi; ?></td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

how to do it? thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate all of the `<p>` elements and adding the text to a variable. I have not tried this, but something like this:

```
$complete = "";
foreach($html->find('div.entry-content p') as $p) 
{
    $complete .= $p->plaintext; 
    echo $p->plaintext;
}
echo $complete;
```

There's a lot of information in the documentation here:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm